# How do I pass gcc optimization level to cmake targets?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake

I have a C project which uses CMake to build with three targets for each library type (static, dynamic and shared):

```
add_library(contact-static STATIC EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL lib/contact.c)
add_library(contact-shared SHARED EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL lib/contact.c)

add_executable(contactbook src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(contactbook contact-static)

add_executable(contactbook-static EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(contactbook-static contact-static)
add_dependencies(contactbook-static contact-static)

add_executable(contactbook-shared EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL src/main.c)
add_dependencies(contactbook-shared contact-shared)
target_link_libraries(contactbook-shared contact-shared)

add_executable(contactbook-dynamic EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL src/main.c)
target_link_libraries(contactbook-dynamic contact-shared)
target_compile_definitions(contactbook-dynamic PRIVATE DYNLIB=true)
target_compile_options(contactbook-dynamic PRIVATE -rdynamic)
target_link_libraries(contactbook-dynamic dl)
```

The problem is that I have to provide optimization level passing to the `make` command.

I have already tried (but in both I've got stuck):

- passing a variable through make comman like `make -Dopt:STRING=0` but i have no idea how to use this as compiler flag
- creating targets for each optimization level, but I can't add definitions to `add_custom_target` targets

So how can I do that and what is the best practice for passing optimization level to cmake target?

Comment: What's wrong with `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O9")`? It's probably not the _best_ way, but it (hopefully; I've been doing that kind of thing in my CMakeLists) works.

Comment: Because I need multiple optimization level build (O0,O1...Os) to compare them and I have no idea how to do that without creating target for each level.

Comment: Each different optimization level is a separate build configuration. As such, you should probably configure each separately in unique build directory, passing the toolchain-specific optimization flag as show in @at-2500's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change any cmake variable when running cmake on the command line like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Os" .
```